# Inline css not being set on button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a button that moves around the screen everytime you hover over it, the up and down motion works, but the left and right doesn't. The button just moves vertically when I want it to move both ways. Code in question:

```
<input type="button" value="Other button" id="otherbutton" style="position: absolute; top:  100px; left: 10px;" 
onmouseover="style.top= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'" 
onmouseover="style.left= Math.floor((Math.random()*500+1) + 'px'">
```

Comment: Thank you guys for all the helpful answers :) 

As an extra, how could I make a button that moves away from the mouse? Not just to a random location on the screen, but actually avoiding the mouse. I'm still learning JavaScript and I'm not sure how, if possible, to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the two into one mouseover. Additionally, you are missing a closing ) in the second mouseover:

```
<input type="button" value="Other button" id="otherbutton" style="position: absolute; top:  100px; left: 10px;" 
onmouseover="style.top= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'; style.left= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'">
```

[Here's a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/G3354/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have same properties twice, set all only in one "onmouseover" property.

```
<input type="button" value="Other button" id="otherbutton" style="position: absolute; top:  100px; left: 10px;"  onmouseover="style.top= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'; style.left= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'">
```

you separe multiple javascript lines with ";" in a same property

Comment: How do I make it do both things on that property?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 2 mouseover handlers - combine them into one:

`<input type="button" value="Other button" id="otherbutton" style="position: absolute; top:  100px; left: 10px;" 
onmouseover="this.style.top= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'; this.style.left= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'">`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/msGnh/

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function move( element ) {
       element.style.top = Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px';
       element.style.left = Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

OR

```
 <input type="button" value="Other button" id="otherbutton" style="position: absolute; top:  100px; left: 10px;" onmouseover="this.style.top= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px';this.style.left= Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1) + 'px'" >
```